# how to display id of input field with respective those value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple forms like shown below:

```js
function chartsubmitbtn() {
  var x = $('#x_axis_t1').val();
  alert(x);
}
```

```html
  
<div id="trace-div1">
  <h4><b>Trace 1 </b></h4>
  <form>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><label>X Axis:  </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="t1_x_axis" id="x_axis_t1" size="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label>Y Axis:  </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="t1_y_axis" id="y_axis_t1" size="50"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="trace-div2">
  <h4><b>Trace 2 </b></h4>
  <form>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><label>X Axis:  </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="t1_x_axis" id="x_axis_t2" size="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label>Y Axis:  </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="t1_y_axis" id="y_axis_t2" size="50"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
<button type="button" id="chart-report-submit" onclick="chartsubmitbtn();">Submit</button>
```

in above code if i click the submit button it will display values with respect there id  .

my expected out put is

```
x_axis_t1 = "x axis t1";
y_axis_t1 = "y axis t1";
x_axis_t2 = "x axis t2";
y_axis_t2 = "y axis t2";
```

in above `x_axis_t1,x_axis_t1,x_axis_t1` and `x_axis_t1` are IDs with respect there input text values.

Comment: You mean the user will fill mentioned values and you want to display them there with input `id` ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Ya exactly .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple $.each loop with input type text selector is enough **$('input[type=text]')**

```js
 function chartsubmitbtn(){
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
     console.log($(this).attr("id")+ '='  +$(this).val()+';');
    })  
  }
```

```html
<html>
     <head>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
     <script>
    function chartsubmitbtn(){
         var x = $('#x_axis_t1').val();
        alert(x);
    }
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div id = "trace-div1">
    <h4><b>Trace 1 </b></h4>
        <form>
          <table>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td><label>X Axis:  </label></td>                                               
                     <td><input type="text" name="t1_x_axis" id="x_axis_t1" size="50"></td>                                         
                  </tr>                                                                             
                  <tr>
                     <td><label>Y Axis:  </label></td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="t1_y_axis" id="y_axis_t1" size="50"></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
       </form>  
    </div> 
    <div id = "trace-div2">
    <h4><b>Trace 2 </b></h4>
        <form>
          <table>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td><label>X Axis:  </label></td>                                               
                     <td><input type="text" name="t1_x_axis" id="x_axis_t2" size="50"></td>                                         
                  </tr>                                                                             
                  <tr>
                     <td><label>Y Axis:  </label></td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="t1_y_axis" id="y_axis_t2" size="50"></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
       </form>  
    </div> 
    <button type="button" id="chart-report-submit"  onclick="chartsubmitbtn();">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**So you want to do something like below?**

```js
    function chartsubmitbtn(){
         var x_axis_t1 = $('#x_axis_t1').val();
         var y_axis_t1 = $('#y_axis_t1').val();
         var x_axis_t2 = $('#x_axis_t2').val();
         var x_axis_t2 = $('#x_axis_t2').val();
         
         console.log('x_axis_t1 => ', x_axis_t1);
         console.log('y_axis_t1 => ', y_axis_t1);
         console.log('x_axis_t2 => ', x_axis_t2);
         console.log('x_axis_t2 => ', x_axis_t2);
        
    }
```

```html
<html>
     <head>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
   
   </head>
   <body>
    <div id = "trace-div1">
    <h4><b>Trace 1 </b></h4>
        <form>
          <table>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td><label>X Axis:  </label></td>                                               
                     <td><input type="text" name="t1_x_axis" id="x_axis_t1" size="50"></td>                                         
                  </tr>                                                                             
                  <tr>
                     <td><label>Y Axis:  </label></td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="t1_y_axis" id="y_axis_t1" size="50"></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
       </form>  
    </div> 
    <div id = "trace-div2">
    <h4><b>Trace 2 </b></h4>
        <form>
          <table>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td><label>X Axis:  </label></td>                                               
                     <td><input type="text" name="t1_x_axis" id="x_axis_t2" size="50"></td>                                         
                  </tr>                                                                             
                  <tr>
                     <td><label>Y Axis:  </label></td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="t1_y_axis" id="x_axis_t2" size="50"></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
       </form>  
    </div> 
    <button type="button" id="chart-report-submit"  onclick="chartsubmitbtn();">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this for getting output as alert**

```js
var str='';
 function chartsubmitbtn(){
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
     str += $(this).attr("id")+ '='  +$(this).val()+';'+'\n';
    });
    alert(str);
 }
```

```html
<html>
     <head>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div id = "trace-div1">
    <h4><b>Trace 1 </b></h4>
        <form>
          <table>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td><label>X Axis:  </label></td>                                               
                     <td><input type="text" name="t1_x_axis" id="x_axis_t1" size="50"></td>                                         
                  </tr>                                                                             
                  <tr>
                     <td><label>Y Axis:  </label></td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="t1_y_axis" id="y_axis_t1" size="50"></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
       </form>  
    </div> 
    <div id = "trace-div2">
    <h4><b>Trace 2 </b></h4>
        <form>
          <table>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td><label>X Axis:  </label></td>                                               
                     <td><input type="text" name="t1_x_axis" id="x_axis_t2" size="50"></td>                                         
                  </tr>                                                                             
                  <tr>
                     <td><label>Y Axis:  </label></td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="t1_y_axis" id="y_axis_t2" size="50"></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
       </form>  
    </div> 
    <button type="button" id="chart-report-submit"  onclick="chartsubmitbtn();">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```